# pandas - select row of maximum value_counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple dataframe df:

```
User,C,G
111,ar,1
112,es,1
112,es,1
112,es,2
113,ca,2
113,ca,3
113,ca,3
114,en,4
```

I grouped that by:

```
result = df.groupby(['User','G'])['C'].value_counts()
```

obtaining:

```
User  G    
111   1  ar    1
112   1  es    2
      2  es    1
113   2  ca    1
      3  ca    2
114   4  en    1
```

My goal is then to keep only the rows with the maximum `value_count` per group, so that the resulting dataframe appears:

```
User  G    
111   1  ar    1
112   1  es    2
113   3  ca    2
114   4  en    1
```

I found also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22710270/get-maximum-of-value-counts-after-groupby) question related to a similar issues, but I can't figured out how to apply that method in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a mask to indicate whether a particular row is `maximum` in its group.

```
mask = result.groupby(level='User').apply(lambda g: g == g[g.idxmax()])
mask

User  G    
111   1  ar     True
112   1  es     True
      2  es    False
113   2  ca    False
      3  ca     True
114   4  en     True
dtype: bool
```

And then, select using this boolean mask

```
result[mask]

User  G    
111   1  ar    1
112   1  es    2
113   3  ca    2
114   4  en    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: What about multiple equal occurrences? Is there a way to select only single maximum values? I mean, sometimes can happen that the maximum values is not unique...