# pandas - groupby, count values and remove equal occurrences

Tags: python, pandas

Starting from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223242/pandas-select-row-of-maximum-value-counts) question and the following dataframe df:

```
U,C,G
111,ar,1
112,es,1
112,es,1
112,es,2
113,en,2
113,en,3
113,en,3
114,ca,4
112,es,1
112,es,1
112,es,1
115,it,1
115,it,2
115,it,3
```

I grouped and count values in this way:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['U','G'])['C'].value_counts()
```

and then keep the maximum per group:

```
mask = grouped.groupby(level='U').apply(lambda g: g == g[g.idxmax()])
grouped = grouped[mask]
```

obtaining:

```
U    G    
111  1  ar    1
112  1  es    5
113  3  en    2
114  4  ca    1
115  1  it    1
     2  it    1
     3  it    1
```

Now some `U` have multiple equal occurrences in values. My goal is to keep only `U` rows with only one occurrence, and discard the others. In this example, the resulting dataframe would discard the `115` group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> grouped[ grouped.groupby(level='U').transform('count') == 1 ]

U    G    
111  1  ar    1
112  1  es    5
113  3  en    2
114  4  ca    1
```

Could also do:

```
>>> grouped[ grouped.groupby(level='U').rank(method='max') == 1 ]
```